# How to redirect one query string to another via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect one URL to another - both contain a query string, but prior to the string, there will be a variation on the pair of rules needed (ie. one rule for English, the other for French).

I have tried a few query string redirects that I found here, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem considering most suggest that the rule should be implemented into the document root htaccess file (below the language directories).

When the following URL is requested:

www.site.com/english/hr/jobs/job_posting.php?id=2019-A-01

I need it to forward to:

www.site.com/french/hr/jobs/job_posting.php?id="2019-A-02

Note that the first subdirectory (language requirement) and the last number (job ID in the data) have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/english\/hr\/jobs\/job_posting.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2019-A-01$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /french/hr/jobs/job_posting.php?id=2019-A-02 [L,R=301]
```